# Count occurances of a value in an entire dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For instance:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({A: ['Sally', 'Mark', 'John', 'Bridget', 'Anthony'], 'B': ['Tim', 'Sally', 'Sally', 'Bridget', 'Mark'], 'C': ['Matt', 'Jeff', 'Carl', 'Tim', 'Gus']})
```

How would I find the amount of times "Sally" appears in all of the columns combined? I'm looking for something more efficient than combining the amount of occurrences for each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```py
(df.values == 'Sally').sum()
```

However, assuming you need to do this for all the unique values, I would suggest using `df.stack().value_counts()` (as also suggested in @BENY's answer).

#### Data

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['Sally', 'Mark', 'John', 'Bridget', 'Anthony'], 
    'B': ['Tim', 'Sally', 'Sally', 'Bridget', 'Mark'], 
    'C': ['Matt', 'Jeff', 'Carl', 'Tim', 'Gus'],
})
# print(df)

#          A        B     C
# 0    Sally      Tim  Matt
# 1     Mark    Sally  Jeff
# 2     John    Sally  Carl
# 3  Bridget  Bridget   Tim
# 4  Anthony     Mark   Gus
```

Answer (score 3):

So chain `stack` with `value_counts`

```
df.stack().value_counts()
Out[113]: 
Sally      3
Tim        2
Bridget    2
Mark       2
John       1
Carl       1
Matt       1
Gus        1
Jeff       1
Anthony    1
dtype: int64
```